# How to enable Collection notifyDataChanged?

Tags: java, android

I have a fragment where I have a ListView with a BaseAdapter.
Then I have a popup menu where I select an option and it adds item to Collection.
The data from collection should be shown in the List, but it doesn't show.
I need to add adapter.notifyDataChanged() to update the view.

The problem is that I may not have access to adapter from different classes. How is it possible to enable auto-ui updating?

PS. I tried to add the data from UI thread, but still nothing...

```
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                        public void run() {
                            GlobalData.groupTable.put(newGroup.getId(), newGroup);

                        }
                    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem is that I may not have access to adapter from different classes.

Create a custom callback to update your Adapter. [This approach](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#CommunicatingWithActivity) is from the Developer's Guide.

Comment: I thought that DataSetObserver implements a callback which indicated change in the data set. Doesn't it?

Comment: The Collection isn't the data set being monitored, the adapter is. (Weird, right?) Look at ArrayAdapter's [`add()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java#ArrayAdapter.add%28java.lang.Object%29) method. You'll notice that even here you must call `notifyDataSetChanged()` to see the changes in your ListView, Spinner, or any other View.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't.  Pass the adapter as a parameter to the class that needs to call it.  Or you can write your own collection class that overrides the add method to call the adapter, but even then you'll have to pass the adapter to the new collection class.

Comment: Does it mean that with native collections I cannot make it update the ui automatically?

Comment: Nope.  There's no way to be notified automatically when variables change.  Something has to explicitly call notifyDataSetChanged.  You can create a Collection class that does it fairly easily (just override add and remove to call it after calling super.add and super.remove).

Comment: I thought that DataSetObserver implements a callback which indicated change in the data set. Doesn't it?